# Why doesn't this MacScript return a valuable on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, applescript

I have the following VBA Script

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = MacScript("choose file name")
MsgBox fileName
```

✅ If I run the AppleScript in Script Editor, and select a pre-existing file, a path is returned.
✅ If I run the AppleScript in Script Editor, and attempt to create a new file, a path is returned.
✅ If I run this in Excel, and select a pre-existing file, a path is returned.
❌ If I run this in Excel, and attempt to create a new file, a path is NOT returned.

What could be going wrong please?

Mac Version: 10.14 (Mojave)
Excel Version: 16.20 (181208)
VBA Version: 7.1

Comment: Wild guess - System Prefs>Security & Privacy>Privacy - look at Full Disk Access & Automation perms

Comment: It sounded like a good guess, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps [`MacScript("ChooseFile")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/macscript-function)?  Do you get any errors currently?  Can VBA access the script `choose file name`?  Does [this page](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac017.htm) help?

Comment: @BruceWayne. Thanks for your reply. `choose file` only allows the selection of pre-existing files. I'd like to be able to create a new file. I assume VBA can access the script because it runs. And the script you link to is even more restrictive, it allows the user to select a folder only.